# Iterating through collection of different types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, void-pointers, type-traits, typelist

**Situation**

I have a template class `TIppImage<T>` for image of type `T`. I have singleton class `CIppMemoryManager` which can store a number of images of different size and type.

```
class CIppMemoryManager
{
public:
  /// ... Singleton interface ... 

  template<class T> TIppImage<T>* GetImage(width, height);

private:
  CIppMemoryManager();
  ~CIppMemoryManager();

  std::map<IppDataType, void*> m_Containers;
};
```

`IppDataType` is enum, which values correspond to actual types. All management is done in template class `TIppImageContainer<T>`. And all specialization of this class is stored in `m_Containers` as a `void*`. It's not very good, but it is at least simple.

With this approach, I can simply implement template `GetImage` method like this:

```
template<class T> TIppImage<T>* CIppMemoryManager::GetImage(width, height)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<TIppImageContainer<T>*>(m_Containers[
    TIppTypeTraits<T>::ipp_data_type])->GetImage(width, height);
}
```

where I'm using traits class `TIppTypeTraits<T>` to obtain enum value from given type.

**Problem**

I cannot simply implement non-template methods like constructor. I need to explicitly handle all possible types:

```
CIppMemoryManager::CIppMemoryManager()
{
  m_Containers[ipp8u] = new CIppImageContainer<Ipp8u>;
  m_Containers[ipp8s] = new CIppImageContainer<Ipp8s>;
  m_Containers[ipp16u] = new CIppImageContainer<Ipp16u>;
  m_Containers[ipp16s] = new CIppImageContainer<Ipp16s>;
  ...
}
```

Worse, for destructor I also need to deal with `void*`:

```
CIppMemoryManager::~CIppMemoryManager()
{
  delete reinterpret_cast<TIppImageContainer<Ipp8u>*>(m_Containers[ipp8u]);
  delete reinterpret_cast<TIppImageContainer<Ipp8s>*>(m_Containers[ipp8s]);
  delete reinterpret_cast<TIppImageContainer<Ipp16u>*>(m_Containers[ipp16u]);
  delete reinterpret_cast<TIppImageContainer<Ipp16s>*>(m_Containers[ipp16s]);
  ...
}
```

So, the questions are:

a) Is there some way to iterate through collection of different types? Cannot use traits class here since function is non-template.

b) Is there some better way to store collection of containers - objects of different type? When they are just a different specialization of common template class, containers itself are pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with polymorphic `CIppImageContainer<T>` (make them all share a common base class) and a smart pointer ?

Or some kind of `boost::variant` ?

Comment: Seems like it will solve `void*` problem for destruction using virtual destructor. Just didn't think about non-template ancestor of template classes. However, `GetImage` cannot be virtual since it uses template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think the class variant from the boost library (`boost::variant`) may help you. You can use visitors to execute the appropriate code depending on the type stored in a variant. A `std::vector<boost::variant<T0, T1,...>>` can store a list of objects of different types.

As your objects are similar, they may have the same size in memory, which is a good thing since `boost::variant` storage is stack-based (no heap allocation - this is faster).

Comment: How will it help iterate through collection of different types?

Comment: Consider some `variant<int, float, double>`, and a structure `my_visitor` with the operator () defined for each type contained in the variant. If `x` is an instance of `variant<int, float, double>`, then `boost::apply_visitor(my_visitor(), x)` will call the appropriate operator() of the visitor depending on the type stored in the variant. Now, if you have a `std::vector<variant<int, float, double>>` you can use `apply_visitor` for each element.

Comment: Hardly believed, to be honest. There is no type information on compile time about some element of the vector, because this is run-time structure. How will it deduce correct overload?.. Or should I just go through implementation of `boost::variant`? :)

Comment: Yes it is runtime detection. Variant internally holds an index indicating what type is stored. You can consider apply_visitor like a switch(index) where each case call the correct overload method.

Comment: Thank you on that! I'm not actually going to use it in this particular problem, but think it may be exploited conveniently in some other case.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::mpl::for_each` is tailor-made for that job. Define a vector of types to operate on, a functor or lambda expression to do something, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::variant` is the most likely candidate but sometimes `variant`S become rather large as they require some extra storage and also have to deal with alignment. So maybe `boost::any` has advantages in some situations as well:

```
std::vector<std::pair< Type, boost::any > > data;
```

To comfortably iterate over such a container is harder (`boost::transform_iterator` cannot have more than one return type, so this wont work without some template trickery).