# C++ iteratively search through mixed type Maps

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a large set of if statements I would like to turn into a loop:

```
if (intParams.find(paramName) != intParams.end()) {
  return (float)intParams.at(paramName);
} else if (floatParams.find(paramName) != floatParams.end()) {
  return (float)floatParams.at(paramName);
} else if (boolParams.find(paramName) != boolParams.end()) {
  return (float)boolParams.at(paramName);
}
return defaultVal;
```

I would like to turn this into a loop or perhaps folding expression to simplify the logic, but it is difficult because intParams has type `Map<string, int64_t>`, floatParams has type `Map<string, float>`, and boolParams has type `Map<string, bool>`. I've tried looking through boost but can't find anything suitable.

I would like to simplify this to something like

```
for (auto& param : {intParams, floatParams, boolParams}) {
  if (param.find(paramName) != param.end()) {
    return (float)param.at(paramName);
  }
}
return defaultVal;
```

Let me know what I can do!

Comment: Why do you have all these different types of map if you always return a `float`?

Comment: Define an a base class with an abstract `find()` method. Implement three subclasses, one for each map. Then this becomes a simple matter of iterating over an on-the-fly constructed array of three pointers to the base class. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @PaulSanders it comes from some other parsing API so I don't have an option to change the underlying Maps.

Comment: [templates - Static duck typing in C++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890357/static-duck-typing-in-c)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6864166/5267751) also suggests a (Boost) function that might work.

Comment: @user202729 Although Boost functions allow iteration with mixed types, I think that they would not be suitable with the nuance of halting early if the value is found. If I use a visitor pattern it will require more code than a long set of if's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float retval=defaultVal;
auto all_maps = [&](auto&...maps){
  auto one_map = [&](auto&map){
    auto it = map.find(paramName);
    if (it==map.end()) return false;
    retval=static_cast<float>(it->second);
    return true;
  };
  return ( one_map(maps) || ... );
};
all_maps(intParams, floatParams, boolParams);
return retval;
```

You can use an optional if you want to avoid assigning over a default.

There are also if constexpr recursive solutions that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a surprising amount with fold expressions and a helper class template:

```
template<class T>
struct Search {
  Search(const Map<std::string,T> &m,const std::string &k)
    : m(m),k(k) {}  // for CTAD (until C++20)

  friend std::optional<float> operator|(const std::optional<float> &f,const Search<U> &s) {
    if(!f)
      if(const auto i=s.m.find(s.k); i!=s.m.end())
        return static_cast<float>(*i);
    return f;
  }

private:
  const Map<std::string,T> &m;
  const std::string &k;
};

template<class ...TT>
float get(const Map<std::string,TT> &...mm,const std::string &k,float defaultVal) {
  return (std::nullopt | ... | Search(mm,k)).value_or(defaultVal);
}
```